# How to localize culture-independent resources for the same locale?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, cultureinfo

Currently I localize my forms and strings by adding a new `resx` file for the specific language. For forms, I set the `Localizable` property to true. I then let the compiler generate the individual satellite assemblies.

However, I have situations where different customers want to have different text for the same form or string resource.

For example, `Product Category` is the standard string for anything related to the product category (form title, strings, labels, etc). However, a particular customer might want to have `Product Type` instead.

Would creating custom cultures solve this problem? (as explained in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Then I might have the standard locale and a custom locale, eg:

```
Strings.resx
Strings-en-US-customer1.resx
```

and for the form:

```
ProductCategoryFrom.resx
ProductCategoryFrom.en-US-customer1.resx
```

Is this the best approach? Will these custom cultures be listed as regions in the Windows locales or are they specific to the application.

Also, how can I set which locale gets compiled so that not all custom locales are available at runtime?